# How to add @Generated annotations to delombok code?

Tags: java, gradle, lombok, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

- Sample multi-module project: https://github.com/overfullstack/my-lab/tree/master/lombok-lab
- Sample single module project: https://github.com/overfullstack/untitled

I have the following lombok.config:

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
lombok.extern.findbugs.addSuppressFBWarnings = true
```

But when I see the generated code in `build/generated/sources/delombok/java/main/...` I don't see `@Generated` annotations. This is affecting my Jacoco test coverage. Please help. Thanks.
(I observed from my single module project that `@Genearated` annotations are being added to classes in `build/classes/java/main/...` but not to `build/generated/sources/delombok/java/main/...`, is this a bug or expected?)

Comment: the location of lombok.config - should be in the source of module, because the build may be disconnected see -- https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration -- Usually, a user of lombok puts a lombok.config file with their preferences in a workspace or project root directory, with the special config.stopBubbling = true key to tell lombok this is your root directory. You can then create lombok.config files in any subdirectories (generally representing projects or source packages) with different settings.

Comment: @PrasadU but I did try the combinations. You may notice from the sample projects, I have `lombok.config` both at root and module level as well.